# Displaying multiple records in one row with duplicate user id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table setup to where awards are tracked by a user id. There will be multiple records with the same user id but different awards.

Current database

```
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| user_id | award_id | award_date          |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
|       1 |       26 | 2016-08-20 00:00:00 |
|       1 |       27 | NULL                |
|       1 |       28 | NULL                |
|       1 |       29 | NULL                |
|       1 |       30 | NULL                |
|       1 |       31 | NULL                |
|       2 |       26 | 2016-08-19 00:00:00 |
|       2 |        2 | NULL                |
|       3 |       36 | NULL                |
|       3 |        2 | NULL                |
|       4 |        1 | NULL                |
|       4 |        2 | NULL                |
|       5 |        1 | NULL                |
|       5 |        2 | NULL                |
|       6 |        6 | 2016-08-23 23:06:48 |
|       6 |        1 | NULL                |
|       2 |       20 | NULL                |
|       3 |       20 | 2016-08-18 00:00:00 |
|       4 |       20 | NULL                |
|       5 |       20 | NULL                |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

The current code I am using is not able to display the records to the user. It will only grab a single result. I have tried removing the GROUP BY but it needs to keep all the records to one row with the multiple results.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM awards ORDER BY id ASC";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$awards = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) )
{
    $awards[] = $row;
}

$asql = "SELECT * FROM ( awards, rosters )
inner join ranks on ranks.id=rosters.rankid
inner join user_awards on user_awards.award_id=awards.id
where rosters.ruser_id = user_awards.user_id AND rosters.rplatoon='viking'
GROUP BY rosters.rname
ORDER BY rosters.rname";
$aresults = mysqli_query($con, $asql);
if(!$aresults and $mysqliDebug) {
    echo "<p>There was an error in query:". $aresults."</p>";
    echo $con->error;
}

$uawards = array();
while ( $arow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresults) )
{
    $uawards[] = $arow;
}
?>

<table >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank/Name</th>
            <?php foreach ($awards as $award)
             {
                 if ($award['category'] == 'medal')
                 {
                    echo '<th style="text-align:center;">
                              <div class="tooltip4">
                                  <div id="award-'. $award['image_name'] . '3">&nbsp;</div>
                                  <span class="tooltiptext4">'. $award['award_name'] .'</span>
                              </div>
                          </th>';
                  }   
              }
             ?>


          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <?php foreach ($uawards as $users )
           {
               echo '<tr><td>' . $users['name'] . ' '. $users['rname'] . '</td>';
                     $medal = 0;
                     foreach ($awards as $award)
                     {
                          if ( $award['category'] == 'medal')
                          {
                              if ( $award['id'] == $users['award_id'])
                              {
                                  $awardid = $users['award_id'];
                                  if ( $awardid == 26 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 27 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 28 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 29 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 30 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 31 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 32 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 33 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 34 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 35 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 36 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 37 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 38 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 39 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( $awardid = 40 )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                                  elseif ( !$awardid )
                                  {
                                      echo '<td>True</td>';
                                  }
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  echo '<td>False</td>';
                              }
                          }
                      }
                      echo '</tr>';
                  } 
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the result

[image]

I hope I worded this correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$asql =   SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(award_id SEPARATOR ',') as awards FROM user_awards GROUP BY user_id
$aresults = mysqli_query($con, $asql);
```

It gives 1 row in a comma separated (In `awards`  `26,27,28,29,30,31` against `user_Id` `1`) 
use `explode` function and `in_array()`

```
   <table >
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Rank/Name</th>
            <?php foreach ($awards as $award)
            {
               if ($award['category'] == 'medal')
               {
                  echo '<th style="text-align:center;">
                  <div class="tooltip4">
                      <div id="award-'. $award['image_name'] . '3">&nbsp;</div>
                      <span class="tooltiptext4">'. $award['award_name'] .'</span>
                  </div>
                  </th>';
               }   
           }
          ?>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        while($arow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresults)
        {
           <tr>
               $award=explode(',',$arow['awards'])?>
               <td>
               <?php
                   if (in_array("26", $award)) echo "true"; 
                   else  echo "false"; 
               ?>
               </td>
               <td><?php
                  if (in_array("27", $award)) echo "true"; 
                  else  echo "false"; 
               ?></td>
           </tr> 
        }?>
    </tbody>
 <table>
```

this an example of two columns, for more columns add them `while` loop

```
<td><?php
    if (in_array("award_id", $award))`replace award_ids to your table Ids` 
       echo "true"; 
    else  echo "false"; 
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for <3

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(award_id SEPARATOR str_val ',')
FROM user_awards
GROUP BY user_id
```

This will give all the awards that the user has in 1 row in a comma separated column. Further joins to the rosters table can be done from here and using joins to the awards table its possible to add the awards's name to the GROUP_CONCAT together with the award_id.

Answer (score 0):

@Mohamed Yasin I agree with your query. But there is limitation in GROUP_CONCAT,

@Ryahn You can increase the GROUP_CONCAT setting by using `group_concat_max_len`. So you should use like this.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; // set value according to requirement. Default is 1024
```

it is a temporary, session-scope, setting. It only applies to the current session You should use it like this.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(award_id SEPARATOR str_val ',')
FROM user_awards
GROUP BY user_id
```

You can do this even in shared hosting, but when you use an other session, you need to repeat the SET SESSION command.

The maximum value for group_concat_max_len is 18446744073709551615.

You can also see more configuration of MYSQL on this link.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

There you can see minimum, maximum, default value, whether you can set them globally or per-session, whether you can change them on a running instance or does it require a restart, and other description of usage.

I hope this will help.